# jquery count li's in top level UL

Tags: jquery, list, count, iteration

I need to count the amount of LI's in a top level UL.

My top level menu has 6 items in it but this could dynamically change. I thought this could work but it is still counting the child li's too :(

```
var numTopNavItems = 0;

$("ul.rmHorizontal > li").each(function (i) {

    numTopNavItems += i;
    alert("numTopNavItems = " + numTopNavItems);
});
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Thanks,
James

Comment: It should work if you change the `+= i` to `+= 1`. What is your HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to count the number of matched element is

```
var numTopNavItems = $("ul.rmHorizontal > li").length;
alert("numTopNavItems = " + numTopNavItems);
```

The method should work as long as only the top level `<ul>` has class `rmHorizontal`. If not, try the selector

```
"ul.rmHorizontal:first > li"
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Got it thanks:

```
var count = $("#myList").children().length;
```

Comment: This will count all children of the `ul`, not just the `li`. Yes, the only things that *should* be direct children of an `ul` are `li` tags, but some pages may not honor this.

Comment: Thanks Piskvor, I have used the example below ;)